# CloseableHttpClient throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, get, httpclient

I tried to retrieve the option chain data from **NSE - India** with get request :

> https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=INFY

when requested from postman client/chrome browser, response came back in 650 ms

[image]

I tried to retrieve the same data from Apache http client

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int timeout = 3;
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000).setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
        try {
//          HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=INFY");
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "*/*");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + statusCode);
            }
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            System.out.println(output);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Records.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Records records = (Records) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(output));
            System.out.println(records);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and it throws **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out**
but i believe time set is enough to get the data.
i tried another get request

> https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
>   It worked fine.

Need some suggestion on how to debug this scenario.

**Here is the stack trace :**
[image]

Comment: Change your code to print a stacktrace and show it to us.  Add it **to the Question**.  We need to know where the exception is being thrown ... in your code, and in the library code you are calling.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it looks like the HTTPS connect has succeeded and you have managed to send the request.

One possible explanation is that nseindia.com is deliberately "slow walking" your request.  This is a tactic that some sites use to deter unwanted requests; e.g. automated requests that are in violation of their Terms of Use.   The idea is that they take ... a ... very ... long ... time ... to respond so that the automation submitting the requests is either deterred entirely or severely limited in what they can do.

Another possibility is that there is a problem in your network infrastructure that is "black holing" some of the network packets coming back from nseindia.com.  (You didn't say if you were running the Java code on the same machine as you were running your web browser.  Or if your web browser is going through a proxy.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, 
I tried setting 
1. "Referer" but it didn't work.
2. "User-Agent" - it worked.
getRequest.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

Comment: If you are having to do that, there is a good chance that you **are** violating their Terms of Use.  You may find that they start taking other more severe actions against you ... like blocking your IP addresses.

Comment: May be but, all the data available is made public by the site. and i changed ("User-Agent", "Karthik");

Comment: *"May be but, all the data available is made public by the site."* - That argument would not be accepted by a law court ... unless you have a really good (== expensive) lawyer.  And possibly not even then.  The data is made available to the public **subject to the published Terms of Use**.  If you ignore the ToU, you are possibly breaking the law.

Comment: thank you for your concern. i will go through their Website-Usage Terms and Conditions thoroughly once.